# How to handle exception when is throws in FlowableOnSubscribe?

Tags: android, observable, rx-java2

```
Flowable.create(new FlowableOnSubscribe<Object>() {
   @Override
   public void subscribe(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull FlowableEmitter<Object> e) throws Exception {
     //throws exceptions, how can I handle error  it using RxJava
   }},BackpressureStrategy.LATEST);
```

Depends on situation it could cause issues, how could be it handled, I don't want to use if condition.

Comment: What do you mean? I don't get what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @GVillani82 It crashes and throws exception in subscribe() method,  because of the code I wrote, but ? I want to handle it by using RxJava error handling

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the onError in your subscriber:

```
.subscribe(new Consumer<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(@NonNull String o) throws Exception {
                        Log.d("test", o);
                    }
                }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(@NonNull Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                        Log.e("test", "throwable: " + throwable.getMessage());
                    }
                });
```

And then the throwable will be handled by the subscriber.